# Inlining web components built with polymer inside one HTML file

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, bundling-and-minification, web-component

I have the following web component built with Polymer:

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html"></link>

<script>
    // register a new element
    Polymer({
        is: "proto-element",
        ready: function () {
            console.log("proto-element is going live...");
            this.innerHTML = "I'm a proto-element. Check out my prototype!";
        }
    });
</script>
```

and I consume it inside the following HTML page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="../bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="import" href="proto-element.html"></link>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="background-color: red; height: 50px;">
            Hey
        </div>

        <proto-element></proto-element>

        <div style="background-color: red; height: 50px;">
            Hey
        </div>

        <proto-element></proto-element>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can find this sample [here](https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/polymer-101/tree/9b83282831b449b197ab06e5e92b306a5aebb5ab/101/101).

What I want to do is to bundle everything into `index.html` file including every link import I have for web components. At the end, index.html file should be on its own. Is it possible to do it in this context?

Comment: Putting the polymer import and the script to register the element inside of index.html

Comment: @user1795832 I want to inline the components as well.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be possible to inline web components with [Vulcanize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vulcanize). After installing vulcanize, running the following command did the trick (output stuff below with `>` is Windows specific):

```
vulcanize index.html > build.html
```

More info: [Concatenating Web Components with Vulcanize](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/articles/concatenating-web-components.html)